# How to programmatically move files into a WebDAV directory

Tags: webdav, cadaver

I would like to programmatically move a group of files from a local directory into a WebDAV directory.

I am guessing a simple batch file would not work because it is a WebDAV directory.  **Note**: the machine is Windows Server 2003 so there is no support for mapping a WebDAV directory to a drive letter so the drive just looks like this: `http://dev1:8080/data/xml` and cannot be made to look like `//dev1/data/xml`

Answer (score 1):

[Cadaver](http://www.webdav.org/cadaver/) may allow you to write a batch script that does all this; otherwise you could use CURL directly, but you'd need to know a bit more about the actual WebDAV protocol (you'd basically need to locally traverse a directory, MKCOL for every subdirectory and PUT for every file).

I'm not sure how well either of these tools compile on Windows, but if it doesn't work out of the box, you could always run it on top of Cygwin. While you're using Cygwin, you can also just create standard shell scripts (/bin/sh or /bin/bash) which will likely actually be easier than windows' .BAT format.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the [BMOVE Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa142722(EXCHG.65).aspx)

Comment: This is proprietary though. Standard WebDAV servers will not support it. Also; this would only work from moves within the WebDAV share. The OP wants to simply do a PUT.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a webdav client such as the one contained in [this project](http://milton.ettrema.com/index.html) (it's Apache Licensed afaik), then basically call it with a batch file / shell script

Answer (score 0):

You can use [python-webdav-library](https://launchpad.net/python-webdav-lib)

```
from webdav import WebdavClient
url = 'https://somesite.net'
mydav = WebdavClient.CollectionStorer(url, validateResourceNames=False)
mydav.connection.addBasicAuthorization(<username>, <password>)

fid = open(<filepath of file you want to upload> ,'rb')
mydav.path = <path to where you want the file to be, ie '/a/b/c.txt'>
mydav.uploadFile(fid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Free [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) (for Windows) supports WebDAV (and WebDAVS). WinSCP supports scripting/command-line operations too.

A sample [WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting) to upload file over WebDAV:

```
open http://user@webdav.example.com/
put file.txt /path/
close
```

Save the script to a file (e.g. `script.txt`) and run it like:

```
winscp.com /script=script.txt
```

You can also put everything on a single line:

```
winscp.com /command "open http://user@webdav.example.com/" ^
    "put file.txt /path/" "close"
```

If you really want to move (not copy) the files, add the `-delete` switch to the [`put` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put):

```
put -delete file.txt /path/
```

See an [introduction to scripting with WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
$filename = 'testing.text';

exec('curl --digest --user "' . $username . ':' . $password . '" -T "' . 
$filename . '" "https://sandbox.test.com/dav/content/" ');
```